# Esperanto Braille display question

Tags: information-technology

Will the accented letters in Esperanto show up when using a Braille display if the Braille display doesn’t specifically support the Esperanto language and if so how would they show up?

Comment: It depends on the display model and the system driving it. Can you provide that information?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this would depend on the Braille tables available in the Braille display's "driver" or screen reader. For example, the open-source Braille translator and formatter [Liblouis](http://liblouis.org/) has [Braille tables](https://github.com/liblouis/liblouis/tree/master/tables) for many languages, including Esperanto. At the bottom of the [Braille table for Esperanto](https://github.com/liblouis/liblouis/blob/master/tables/eo-g1.ctb) I find the following codes for a number of accented letters:

```
uplow Ĉĉ 146        LATIN LETTER C WITH CIRCUMFLEX
uplow Ĝĝ 12456      LATIN LETTER G WITH CIRCUMFLEX
uplow Ĥĥ 1256       LATIN LETTER H WITH CIRCUMFLEX
uplow Ĵĵ 2456       LATIN LETTER J WITH CIRCUMFLEX
uplow Ŝŝ 2346       LATIN LETTER S WITH CIRCUMFLEX
uplow Ŭŭ 346        LATIN LETTER U WITH BREVE
```

Liblouis is used in the open-source screen readers NVDA (for Windows) and Orca (for the Gnome desktop on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Esperanto accented letters are almost exclusive to Esperanto I'd say there's a slim chance the display would support them.